# Mysql query mysql_num_rows not working

Tags: mysql

Here is the example code.Please help me.

```
$query=mysql_query("set @row_count=0;SELECT *,@row_count := @row_count+1 as rank FROM users WHERE username='$username' ");
$numrows=mysql_num_rows($query);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the other way in doing `ROW_NUMBER()` function. See Below:

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT @row_count:=@row_count+1 AS rank, * FROM users, (SELECT @row_count:=0) AS A WHERE username='$username'");
$numrows=mysql_num_rows($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * , count(*) as rank FROM users WHERE username='$username' ");
$numrows=mysql_num_rows($query);
```

Comment: @vamsikr what's the rank here just the count of number of rows returned by query?

Comment: yes but the final array we need to show rank also.@noob